# Pi4 backup/restore of /rootfs partition from bkup_rpimage

Tags: backup, restore

I've done a `bkup_rpimage` onto a USB3 drive using:

https://github.com/lzkelley/bkup_rpimage

From: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=12079

But try as I may, I haven't found a tutorial or post showing how to *restore*. Must exist, though ?

Just looked through all the possible answers that Search threw up here. Nothing definitive that seems to anser the question. I've done a full /home backup to a USB3 external drive using Deja Dup and this programme does offer a Restore option.

Doesn't answer the /rootfs backup/recover question. I did the bkup_rpimage install/backup to the external drive ... no answer to "how to restore" that I've found. Confusing - a backup with no restore capability ?

Comment: What software did you use to make the backup?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dougie. I used bkup_rpimage from the Raspberry Pi Backup thread (I researched many, all of them seemed cavalier about Restore. Incomplete comments, unrelated code etc). I have a backup image and it also works incrementally (good !!), but the Restote comments were not done, I think, although promised. Restore by Win32Imager appears the only choice. This is clunky and as I'm using a 128Gb card, takes about 2 hours to re-write. Surely Linux has done better ?

Comment: As far as I understand you want to shutdown the RasPi, put its SD Card in a card reader on another computer and take an image, isn't it? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo - thank you for your reply. Actually, writing a backup image to a new card on another computer is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Cumbersome. Writing a backed-up image to another card on the Pi (and so periodically swapping them as backup) is really what I'm trying for. I do have a bkup_rpimage on external USB disk now, which is recognised as *.img by both Win32 and Etcher, but I would like to burn that .img to another card in the Pi. Can be done ?

Comment: Update - about 24 hours, not 6 but anyway. I have what seems to me an elegant answer. Pi was running on a 128Gb card in its' undersocket. I put a 64Gb card (formatted on Win7 in NTFS) in a Pi  USB2 socket and used SD Copy from the Menu. I'd tried that on a 32Gb card and it fell over. Not this time, though. The copy went ahead and actually booted Pi just fine when finished and replacing the 128Gb. Everything is there - so Pi backed up 128Gb to 64Gb without data loss & retained /boot,  /rootfs systems. So I can start to build my mapping work now. Thanks to Dougie & Ingo for replying.

Comment: Please make an answer for your solution and accept it with a click on the tick on its left side after two days. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: There are a few highly voted posts about Pi backup on this site. Why you would you ask about a random 6 year old post you found on the internet.

Comment: It's not clear what backup software you're talking about, but if it doesn't have a working restore function it seems rather useless.

Comment: I've edited in a link to what is presumably the script in question; if this is not the case, please correct it.  Ianl07, if it is not clear already, part of the issue here is that the script is pretty obscure (I've never heard of it and I've been a mod here for 5+ years; there are only two places it is mentioned out of our 25+ K questions).  The best place to inquire about the script is probably in the Foundation forum thread (note that we are independent from them), or via the github page.  You will be waiting a long time for a user of it to wander by and notice this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know this:
https://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/de/raspberry/23-pi-erstellt-automatisch-backups-von-sich-selbst-pi-creates-automatic-backups-of-itself/

I use it for backing up th whole pi, including an rootfs on external drive.

raspiBackup helps to create backups of a running Raspberry with no shutdown or manual intervention which means your can save or clone your SD card during normal operation. An exported root partition will be saved too. Important services will be stopped just before starting the backup and are started again when the backup finished. Any device which can be mounted on Linux can be used as backupspace (USB disk, USB stick, nfs, samba, sshfs, ...). The backup image can be created with dd, tar or rsync using hardlinks. Restore is possible on Windows or Linux. Raspberry USB boot images and NOOBs images are supported.

With raspiBackup you can create regular backups of your Raspberry. In addition you can restore a backup to any SD card. A new partition table is created on the target SD card and the backup data is restored on the partitions. If an external root filesystem was saved with raspiBackup this filesystem will also be restored to an external device.